# Import Android SQLite database with Java desktop program

Tags: java, android, sqlite, import

For the program I am developing, I need for a Java application to be able to access a database stored in the android /data/data/package/databases folder. Is there any way that this could be done automatically, or the database has to be imported manually ?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

My investigation lead to the conclusion that one cannot access the /data directory in Android. So, my solution to the problem will be (because I still have not implemented it) to store the database in the SDCard and then access it from the Java application (which I believe will be straightforward).